# Как вызвать Toast.makeText из статического метода (static method)?

Tags: android-studio

Как вызвать `Toast.makeText` из статического метода?
В качестве параметров контекста  пробовал передавать `getContext()`, `getBaseContext()`, `getApplicationContext()`, `this`, `getActivity()`, но к ним нет доступа.

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У статического метода не доступа к контексту. Для того что бы вызвать сообщение из него, передайте `Context` в качестве входящего параметра. Например:

```
public static void test(Context context) {
    ...
    Toast.makeText(context, "This is my Toast message!",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
}
```